# Goodix touchscreen driver modules loads with wrong abs_x_max and abs_y_max

Tags: linux, drivers, yocto-project

I am loading a goodix touchscreen driver on my yocto image for raspberry-pi cm3.
When the pi boots up. The module loads successfully but I get a wrong value for abs_x_max and abs_y_max.

```
[    3.062137] Goodix-TS 3-0014: ID 911, version: 1060
[    3.064672] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: Qualcomm, Incorporated
[    3.075107] usb 1-1.2: SerialNumber: 542162a3
[    3.083645] bcm2835_mmal_vchiq: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[    3.084211] Goodix-TS 3-0014: goodix_read_config: called goodix_i2c_read(0x8047)
[    3.091102] bcm2835_mmal_vchiq: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[    3.112015] Goodix-TS 3-0014: goodix_read_config: abs_x_max=800
[    3.117939] Goodix-TS 3-0014: goodix_read_config: abs_y_max=480
[    3.123935] Goodix-TS 3-0014: goodix_read_config: int_trigger_type=0
[    3.130282] Goodix-TS 3-0014: goodix_read_config: max_touch_num=5
[    3.136640] input: Goodix Capacitive TouchScreen as /devices/platform/ffffffff.i2c/i2c-3/3-0014/input/input0
[    3.146813] Goodix-TS 3-0014: goodix_configure_dev: ts->client->irq=166
[    3.153499] Goodix-TS 3-0014: goodix_request_irq: calling devm_request_threaded_irq(166)
[    3.161852] Goodix-TS 3-0014: >>>>Registering polling function.
[    3.167796] Goodix-TS 3-0014: >>>>Finished registering
```

However my screen is 600X1024 and not 800X480. Why is this happening and is there a way to reset the abs_x_max and abs_y_max? Can I change it through my device tree overlay files?

Comment: *"Why is this happening"* --  Simple code inspection indicates that these resolution numbers come from reading the I2C interface of the device (and confirmed by the boot log you posted).  *"Can I change it through my device tree overlay files?"* -- Yes, the goodix driver allows that.  Try defining properties for  `touchscreen-size-x` and `touchscreen-size-y` in the DT to override.

Comment: @sawdust So does this mean that my screen resolution is being read wrong. I have defined my frame_buffer width and frame_buffer height in config.txt. I thought thats where we are suppose to set it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally found out. That the firmware on the chip was wrong.
Which gave the screen a resolution of 800X480.
Once I changed the screen. I can now see 1024 X 600